# Should I add .idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser to .gitignore?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gitignore, android-studio-3.1

I updated my Android Studio [from 3.0.1 to 3.1](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html), and noticed an unfamiliar file in my existing project:

```
.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser
```

It doesn't depend on whether you update the Android Gradle plugin to [the latest 3.1.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#3-1-0); once I opened an existing project in Android Studio 3.1, it automatically created the file `build_file_checksums.ser`, even if I kept the project to use the previous 3.0.1 plugin as follows.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
}
```

I also created a new project in Android Studio 3.1, and found that the file `build_file_checksums.ser` was created from the beginning.

At the time of writing, there seems to be no official documents on this. I would appreciate it if anyone could find it.

---

#### Edited:

I [inspected](https://superuser.com/a/1107072/889304) the content with [jdeserialize-1.2](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jdeserialize/downloads), as [Samuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6245697/) pointed out that it seems to include some system paths.

```
$ java -jar ~/Downloads/jdeserialize-1.2.jar .idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser 
read: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectBuildFileChecksums _h0x7e0002 = r_0x7e0000;  
//// BEGIN stream content output
com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectBuildFileChecksums _h0x7e0002 = r_0x7e0000;  
//// END stream content output

//// BEGIN class declarations (excluding array classes)
class java.util.HashMap implements java.io.Serializable {
    float loadFactor;
    int threshold;
}

class com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectBuildFileChecksums implements java.io.Serializable {
    long myLastGradleSyncTimestamp;
    java.util.Map myFileChecksums;
}

//// END class declarations

//// BEGIN instance dump
[instance 0x7e0004: 0x7e0003/java.util.HashMap
  object annotations:
    java.util.HashMap
        [blockdata 0x00: 8 bytes]
        [String 0x7e0005: "settings.gradle"]
        [array 0x7e0007 classdesc [cd 0x7e0006: name [B uid -5984413125824719648]: [arraycoll sz 16 -89, -2, 26, -61, -111, 105, -75, -27, 40, 90, 94, 83, 102, 47, 37, 27]
        [String 0x7e0008: "build.gradle"]
        [array 0x7e0009 classdesc [cd 0x7e0006: name [B uid -5984413125824719648]: [arraycoll sz 16 70, 101, -14, 32, 100, -60, -85, -103, 73, -86, 15, 54, -45, 125, 50, 39]
        [String 0x7e000a: "local.properties"]
        [array 0x7e000b classdesc [cd 0x7e0006: name [B uid -5984413125824719648]: [arraycoll sz 16 -107, 64, 60, -33, -18, 18, 56, -84, 15, 0, -86, -73, -27, 127, -94, 27]
        [String 0x7e000c: "/Users/qtmfld/.gradle/gradle.properties"]
        [array 0x7e000d classdesc [cd 0x7e0006: name [B uid -5984413125824719648]: [arraycoll sz 16 -44, 29, -116, -39, -113, 0, -78, 4, -23, -128, 9, -104, -20, -8, 66, 126]
        [String 0x7e000e: "gradle.properties"]
        [array 0x7e000f classdesc [cd 0x7e0006: name [B uid -5984413125824719648]: [arraycoll sz 16 16, -69, 118, 80, -49, -19, 41, -8, 56, -86, 64, -63, 112, -14, 98, 47]
        [String 0x7e0010: "app/build.gradle"]
        [array 0x7e0011 classdesc [cd 0x7e0006: name [B uid -5984413125824719648]: [arraycoll sz 16 -3, -11, 63, -26, 67, -41, -100, 33, 85, -59, -49, -3, -90, 53, -106, 94]

  field data:
    0x7e0003/java.util.HashMap:
        threshold: 12
        loadFactor: 0.75
]
[instance 0x7e0002: 0x7e0000/com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectBuildFileChecksums
  field data:
    0x7e0000/com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.ProjectBuildFileChecksums:
        myFileChecksums: r0x7e0004: java.util.HashMap _h0x7e0004 = r_0x7e0003;  
        myLastGradleSyncTimestamp: 1522297024540
]
//// END instance dump

$
```

You can see the following strings in `java.util.HashMap`.

- "settings.gradle"
- "build.gradle"
- "local.properties"
- "/Users/qtmfld/.gradle/gradle.properties"
- "gradle.properties"
- "app/build.gradle"

[Wh0](https://github.com/wh0) has clarified the same result on Android Studio 3.2 Preview.
https://wh0.github.io/2018/02/17/build-file-checksums-ser.html

Comment: I personnaly added it to gitignore since it seems to include system pathes, and as build folder a cache folder souldn't be under version control

Comment: @Samuel Following your suggestion, I inspected the content and added the result as above. Thanks.

Comment: I have filed this issue in the public issue tracker.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77544553

Comment: [The issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77544553) has been marked as "Fixed". On May 4, it was accepted and fixed. I'm not sure how it has been fixed. The repositories ([AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidProject/root/project_ignore) and [JetBrains GitHub](https://github.com/JetBrains/adt-tools-base/blob/master/templates/gradle-projects/NewAndroidProject/root/project_ignore)) are not updated. It's still in [private codelines](https://source.android.com/setup/start/codelines#private-codelines).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All files in your `.idea` folders are related to your IDE (Android Studio in this case). And as you said this files is created at the opening of the project. So you should add this file to your `.gitignore` because these files can contains some content that is not necessary like your absolute path.

Comment: I added it to my .gitignore, because it contains a string "/Users/qtmfld/.gradle/gradle.properties". It's a absolute path in my home directory.

Comment: Exactly, because this file is created by your IDE.

Comment: Why did you downvoting my answer while is agree with me and validated my answer ?...  @EfiMK

Comment: @Itoun for some reason I thought he said he didn't add it (which I think is the right answer), I don't mind reverting the downvote, but I can't, you have to edit the answer before I can do it

Comment: He said he added it because the file contains absolute path. Look at his comment above. I just edited my answer to fill it

Comment: The official documentation by IntelliJ (the makers of Android Studio) recommend storing some of the files in `.idea` in version control, but not all of them. Link: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems

Answer (score 30):

You should add it to `.gitignore`. Don't include it in your `git add`.

In the left-side **Project** window,

(**a**) change the **Android view** to [the **Android project view**](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/#ProjectView), with the pull-down menu.
(**b**) You can see `build_file_checksums.ser` in folder `.idea/caches`.
(**c**) Open `.gitignore` of the project root directory. (Don't confuse it with `.gitignore` of the **app** module.)

In the right-side `.gitignore` content,

(**d**) add `/.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser`.

[image]

---

[JetBrain's guide](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839) told that you should share

> - All the files under **.idea** directory in the project root **except** the **workspace.xml** and **tasks.xml** files which store user specific settings

and it also said

> You may consider **not to share** the following:
>
> - **.iml** files for the **Gradle** or **Maven** based projects, since these files will be generated on import
> - **gradle.xml** file, see this discussion
> - user **dictionaries** folder (to avoid conflicts if other developer has the same name)
> - XML files under **.idea/libraries** in case they are **generated from Gradle or Maven** project

Therefore, the default `.gitignore` for new projects in Android Studio is:

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/libraries
/.idea/modules.xml
/.idea/workspace.xml
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
.externalNativeBuild
```

But, the `build_file_checksums.ser` file is a Java serialized object, which contains hash and timestamp of:

- "settings.gradle"
- "build.gradle"
- "local.properties"
- "/Users/(**User Name**)/.gradle/gradle.properties"
- "gradle.properties"
- "app/build.gradle"

So, it seems like [the issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77544553) was priority P2 and severity S2, and has been already accepted and fixed. I look forward to future release, in which the default `.gitignore` includes

```
/.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser
```